# (material-components-web) How to change background color of google material theme?

Tags: material-components-web

I am having problem changing default colors for Google's Material Design theme. Primary and secondary colors have been changed, but background and surface colors are not changing. I have attached my code here for reference. Any clue would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```css
@import "colors";

$mdc-theme-primary: $primary;
$mdc-theme-on-primary: if(mdc-theme-contrast-tone($mdc-theme-primary) == "dark", $dark, $light);

$mdc-theme-secondary: $secondary;
$mdc-theme-on-secondary: if(mdc-theme-contrast-tone($mdc-theme-secondary) == "dark", $dark, $light);

$mdc-theme-background: $dark;

$mdc-theme-surface: scale-color($dark, $lightness: 5%);
$mdc-theme-on-surface: if(mdc-theme-contrast-tone($mdc-theme-secondary) == "dark", $dark, $light);

$mdc-theme-error: $red;
$mdc-theme-on-error: if(mdc-theme-contrast-tone($mdc-theme-secondary) == "dark", $dark, $light);

@import "@material/theme/mdc-theme";
```